# How do I provide a non-global callback when loading Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, prototypejs

I am only able to download the Google Maps v3 API when the callback is a global function:

```
function onMapLoad() {
    alert('API is loaded');
}

var script = new Element(
    'script', {
        type: 'text/javascript',
        src: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' 
            + Map.API_KEY
            + '&sensor=false&callback=onMapLoad'
    }
);

document.body.appendChild(script);
```

I don't want to use a global function. Instead I want to call a method on a singleton: `Map.instance().onLoaded`.

```
// ...
+ '&sensor=false&callback=Map.instance().onLoaded'
// ...
```

When I attempt to do this, there is a NetworkError: 403 Forbidden on loading Google's scripts. This seems to imply that Google's service did not like my callback function string. There's no problem with the callback function itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the google loader call

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`

`google.load("maps", "3", {"other_params": "sensor=false","callback" : Map.instance().onLoaded });`

https://developers.google.com/loader/

Comment: According to the documentation, `google.load` is only supported for Maps v2. I tried it on v3 and it said "*The Google Maps API server rejected your request. The "sensor" parameter specified in the request must be set to either "true" or "false".*" Specifying `other_params:{sensor:false}` does not help either.

Comment: Sorry I should have put the sensor in the javascript line try this `google.load("maps", "3", {"other_params": "sensor=false","callback" : Map.instance().onLoaded });`

Comment: The reason this works is because the loader script sends itself as the callback which wraps your callback (with the parens `()`) in a function

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Google doesn't like the function call `()` part of your callback string, but it doesn't have any issues with the fact that it's not global on the document.

I too get a 403 on this:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=4&sensor=false&callback=Map.mapLoaded%28%29

But not this:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=4&sensor=false&callback=Map.instance.mapLoaded

Seems like if you could just specify a function property of the Map object for the callback instead of the return value of the `instance()` function, you can avoid the extra global. I didn't see anything regarding this in their API, but I didn't spend too long looking into that.

---

I haven't had to use JSONP tactics in a long while, so I wasn't sure if this was a limitation of JSONP requiring callbacks to be global or just something that Google was imposing. It seems to be a Google-only thing, as this JSONP test site seems to have no issues with the parens as the response and fiddle show:

http://date.jsontest.com/?callback=Map.foo%28%29

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6WawP/

Hope this helps